# For fun, how many paths are there in a flow matrix?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

I just got done doing the whole flow-matrix percolation exercise in programming.  That is a situation where you have, for simplicity, an $n\times n$ grid of 0s and 1s.  0s represent blocked sites and 1s represent open sites.  You imagine that water is poured over the top of the grid so that water flows through open sites but is unable to pass through closed sites.  So an example grid could be

```
1 0 1 1 1 
1 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 1
```

Again for simplicity, the fluid flows only left-right and up-down, not diagonally.  So this grid percolates because the fluid could enter any of the 1s in the top row.  From there everything can flow down until, on the right-hand side, it flows to the bottom.  If I use `f` to represent a site filled with water, this would fill as

```
f 0 f f f
f f f 0 f
0 0 0 0 f
1 0 f 0 f
1 0 f f f
```

Now I ran Monte Carlo simulations to get the probability that an $n\times n$ matrix percolates, given that any site in the matrix has a probability $p$ of being open.

When finished I thought, "I know probability pretty well.  Rather than just rely on a stupid Monte Carlo simulation, I should find the probability *analytically*." After about five seconds of considering how to do this, I decided it sounds like a beast of a problem.

After idly considering it, I thought maybe the best strategy would be to count every path through the matrix and then count the number of them that percolate.  That sounds simultaneously terrible and the best I've come up with.  Anyone have suggestions?